# KeyError While Writing GroupedBy Dynamic .csv Files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pandas-groupby, keyerror

I have a set of 100 twitter accounts that I have been scraping the tweets from via snscrape. Due to the sheer number of twitter handles, I've been looking for ways of programmatically accomplishing each step. So far I've been able to programmatically scrape every tweet from each of the twitter accounts using for loops and the var() function, but now that I am trying to save I'm getting a keyerror.

My approach so far has been as follows:

1. Create list of twitter handles.

```
handles=['handle1', 'handle2', 'handle3']
```

2. Create empty lists for the data from each tweet to be saved to.

```
    for handle in sanitized_twitter_handles:
        Dynamic_Variable_Name = "tweets_list"+handle
        vars()[Dynamic_Variable_Name] = []
```

3. Run some functions from snscrape to scrape twitter data and load it into each of the created lists programmatically. The dataframe structure this results in is something like this for each of the created dataframes after applying some date extraction functions:

```
                                                         tweets_listhandle1
                   Datetime              Tweet Id                    Text               Username    year    month
    0   2021-03-17 20:21:21+00:00   1097298925851811841     text 1 text 1 text 1 ...    handle1     2021    3
    1   2021-03-17 19:32:19+00:00   1902269509419232769     text 2 text 2 text 2 ...    handle1     2021    3
    2   2021-03-17 15:49:01+00:00   1092093391025184775     text 3 text 3 text 3 ...    handle1     2021    3
    3   2021-03-17 14:04:54+00:00   0072187198827753218     text 4 text 4 text 4 ...    handle1     2021    3
    4   2021-03-16 22:16:50+00:00   0071948009458852868     text 5 text 5 text 5 ...    handle1     2021    3
```

4. Use the groupby function in concert with vars() to create a separate series object for each handle, grouped by year.

```
for handle in sanitized_twitter_handles:
    Dynamic_Variable_Name3 = "tweets_df_"+handle
    Dynamic_Variable_Name4 = "grouped_series_"+handle
    vars()[Dynamic_Variable_Name4]=vars()[Dynamic_Variable_Name3].groupby('year')['Text'].agg('/'.join)
```

5.Convert each of these objects into dataframes once more.

```
for handle in sanitized_twitter_handles:
    Dynamic_Variable_Name4 = "grouped_series_"+handle
    Dynamic_Variable_Name5 = "grouped_df_"+handle
    vars()[Dynamic_Variable_Name5]=vars()[Dynamic_Variable_Name4].to_frame()
```

The resulting dataframes look like this:

```
                                             Text
year                                                   
2011  text 1 text 1 text 1 text 2 text 2 text 2...
2012  text 3 text 3 text 3 text 4 text 4 text 4...
2013  text 5 text 5 text 5 text 6 text 6 text 6...
```

6. Everything has gone smoothly up to this point, but when I got to write the batch of dataframes to csvs, an error is triggered.

```
for handle in sanitized_twitter_handles:
    Dynamic_Variable_Name5 = "grouped_df_"+handle
    Dynamic_File_Name='grouped_by_year_df_'+handle+'.csv'
    vars()[Dynamic_Variable_Name5].to_csv(vars()[Dynamic_File_Name], sep=',', fieldnames=['Year', 'Text'], index=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-431028213c91> in <module>
      2     Dynamic_Variable_Name5 = "grouped_df_"+handle
      3     Dynamic_File_Name='grouped_by_year_df_'+handle+'.csv'
----> 4     vars()[Dynamic_Variable_Name5].to_csv(vars()[Dynamic_File_Name], sep=',', index=True)

KeyError: 'grouped_by_year_df_handle1.csv'
```

I thought maybe the headers had been corrupted, and tried adding the fieldnames (fieldnames=['Year', 'Text']) function to the .to_csv command. I also thought maybe the characters in the tweets weren't playing nice with the .csv file format, and changed the encoding method (encoding='utf-8'). Regardless, I still get KeyErrors.

Any advice about how to write these 100 variables to individual csv files would be appreciated. I would rather not manually write each file to .csv.

Comment: this doesn't require vars() `vars()[Dynamic_File_Name]` use just `Dynamic_File_Name`, instead

Comment: @RishabhKumar Thanks! That was exactly the tip I needed!